# md5srypt in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nodes, postfix-mta

I need use in **NodeJS** password encrypt like in **Postfix.Admin**. I found article about [md5crypt](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/tcllib/md5crypt/md5crypt.html).

How can I use the same encryption in **NodeJS**, because most of function in **NodeJS** are not available ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs). I use this package in my applications.

Comment: The password is too long tah in postfix. `var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10); var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("B4c0/\/", salt);` Use code from example.

Comment: For me it is working:
https://runkit.com/588f2ec75999a1001580b4c9/588f2ec75999a1001580b4ca

Comment: bcrypt - $2a$10$tBQ7j6NngbnvwE120uwctOipiJvt7tATPnp0nXGSr0oko1W2USKyu
postfix - $1$03c2e699$UVOCIE373vq1kqtkIub0M/